# How to delete records through jQuery datatable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datatable, datatables

I am using datatables with checkboxes. I need to implement a functionality to delete a row on selecting the row thorugh a checkbox and clicking the delete button. The datatable is implemented on the server side. Whenever a user selects a row and clicks on the delete button, he needs to be able to visually see that the row gets deleted. I do not understand how to do this. I am trying to use fnDraw(), but do not understand how it works. Any help is highly appreciated. This is how I made the server side ajax call through data table.

```
  var oTable= $('#example').DataTable({
  "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",

            "ajax" : {
                "url" : BASE_URL +"swethasemail/mail-ajax/get-data-table/format/json/",
                "dataType": "json"
            },
            "columnDefs": [{
                        "targets": 0,
                        "orderable": false,
                        "className": "dt-body-center",
                        "render": function(data, type, full, meta){
                                    console.log(data);
                             return '<input class="bbe_bugs_email_multicheck bbe_prevent_default" type="checkbox"  />';

                             },

            }],
            "aoColumns": [
                          { "sWidth": "5%" }, // 1st column width 
                          { "sWidth": "15%" }, // 2nd column width 
                          { "sWidth": "20%" }, // 3rd column width and so on 
                          {"sWidth": "1%"},
                          {"sWidth": "3%"},
                          {"sWidth": "10%"},
                          {"sWidth": "45%"}
                            ],
            "order": [],
            'rowCallback': function(row,data,dataIndex){
                            var rowId=data[0];


                }
            });
```

Comment: Where is the code the question is actually about, i.e your attempt to delete rows ...?

Comment: function bbe_redraw_email_tables()
{
 $(".tip-twitter").remove();
 oTable.fnDraw();
 dTable.fnDraw();
}

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use "CreatedRow" callback or "fnCreatedRow"(fnCreatedRow is the old api, i think you can use either of them. Datatable documentation is really confusing). In this callback, find your delete button and assign the click eventhandler for it which will call remove() method of the datatable plugin. Below is the sample code.

Here is the link for the documentation of remove method: https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().remove()

```
   var oTable= $('#example').DataTable({
           "processing": true,
  "serverSide": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",

        "ajax" : {
            "url" : BASE_URL +"swethasemail/mail-ajax/get-data-table/format/json/",
            "dataType": "json"
        },
        "columnDefs": [{
                    "targets": 0,
                    "orderable": false,
                    "className": "dt-body-center",
                    "render": function(data, type, full, meta){
                                console.log(data);
                         return '<input class="bbe_bugs_email_multicheck bbe_prevent_default" type="checkbox"  />';

                         },

        }],
        "aoColumns": [
                      { "sWidth": "5%" }, // 1st column width 
                      { "sWidth": "15%" }, // 2nd column width 
                      { "sWidth": "20%" }, // 3rd column width and so on 
                      {"sWidth": "1%"},
                      {"sWidth": "3%"},
                      {"sWidth": "10%"},
                      {"sWidth": "45%"}
                        ],
        "order": [],
        "fnCreatedRow": function(tr, trData, iDataIndex) {
           //assuming the first cell in the table has Delete button
           $(tr.cells[0]).find(":button").on("click", function (e) {
                   $(tr).remove();
                   oTable.draw();
               });
         })
```

Comment: function bbe_redraw_email_tables()
{
 $(".tip-twitter").remove();
 oTable.fnDraw();
 dTable.fnDraw();
}

Comment: Is it possible to use .fnDraw(); or table.ajax.reload();

Comment: Either fnDraw() or draw() works. I am not sure which version of datatable you are using. fnDraw() is the legacy method, i think it is still supported in jquery datatable.  http://legacy.datatables.net/ref . did you try ? did it work ? Regarding table.ajax.reload(), did you refer the documentation, why do you want to load the data again? it will keep the table row.